# MongoDB C# driver Method Not Found MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializationInfo ByRef

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-query, bson

I am trying to get some results from `MongoDB` using `C# driver` (Latest driver Version 2.0.1.27).

This is how I call the mongo :

```
 public static async Task < List < MomLogModel >> MomLogAr(MomLogArModel arama) {
     var asd = Builders < MomLogModel > .Filter.Where(a => a.SipID == arama.SipID);
     asd = asd & Builders < MomLogModel > .Filter.Where(a => a._id == arama._id);
     var donucek = await mongoContex.MomLog.Find(asd).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 }
```

This is the class of MomLogModel :

```
 public class MomLogModel {
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [BsonElement("g")]
    public BsonDocument gelen {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [BsonElement("t")]
    public DateTime YaratTarih {
    get {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
    set {
        YaratilisTarih = value;
    }
    }

    [BsonElement("m")]
    public string MesajKod {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [BsonElement("re")]
    public bool Rar {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [BsonElement("kz")]
    public double KaZa {
    get;
    set;
    }

    [BsonElement("si")]
    public int SipID {
    get;
    set;
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error :

```
Method not found: 'Boolean MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonArraySerializer.TryGetItemSerializationInfo(MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializationInfo ByRef)'.
```

I have tried removing the `BsonRepresentation` from model but it didn't solve the issue.

Also tried changing it but cannot figure out what is causing the problem at all.

Comment: This generally happens you have two different projects depending on different versions of the assembly. One version is overwriting the other one. Please check all your projects and packages.config files and ensure they are all referencing the same version of the driver.

Comment: @CraigWilson actually it is a single dll which acceses the mongo db, so there is only 1 single reference to mongo driver.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the Mongo drivers and no change

Answer (score 5):

It appears that , in a project which i was adding this projects dll , I had MongoDB.Bson and its version was an older one.

So having 2 difference versions referencing was causing the problem as @CraigWilson suggested.

Updating the reference resolved the issue.

Comment: In my case I have to do a downgrade.